# Vertical align inside anchor tag without using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

As I said in title. I have to centering content inside an anchor tag. I can use line-height, but some of them contain pseudo element so I am finding another approach to gain what I need. I am using flexbox, but I am told that's abusing way to use. Could you please give me some suggestion? Please check code snippet as well.

If you have any more specific detail in this case, please tell me.

Thanks in advance!

```css
a {
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 80px;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 120px;
}

.without-pseudo:before {
  content: none;
}
  
a:hover {
  background: green;
}
  
a:before {
  content: ':before';
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">text</a>
<a href="#" class="without-pseudo">text</a>
```

Comment: Flexbox is **not** an abusing way, just one way, and likely the best if you might have more than 1 line of text. It is also made for simplify things like vertical centering

Comment: Might also want to explore wrapping the text in another `inline` element, like a `span`, then take it out of the document flow with `position: absolute`, the parent `a` tag will need to be `position: relative`, you can now position the `absolute` child relative to it's parent element declaring `top` and `bottom` rules, e.g: `top: 0; bottom: 0` - that should steer you in the right direction, you may still need to apply further rules in conjunction.

Comment: The content looks centered to me, what am I missing here?

Comment: @Sheedo OP uses Flexbox, which does the job, though someone told **not** to use it, which is what is asked for

Comment: @LGSon I don't get why it is "abusing" to use flexbox for vertical alignment, it's perfectly fine to me.

Comment: @Sheedo It is, hence I answered with just that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am using flexbox, but I am told that's abusing way to use.

No, it's **not** abusive using Flexbox for this task, it's one of the things it does excellent.

The only reason not to, is to support very old browsers that doesn't support it, which *Paulie* *D's* answer has an alternative for.

---

Updated

If you can wrap the text inside the anchor, you can also center it using `transform: translate`

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  height: 80px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 120px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
}

a span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;  
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.without-pseudo span:before {
  content: none;
}
  
a:hover {
  background: green;
}
  
a span:before {
  content: ':before';
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><span>text</span></a>
<a href="#" class="without-pseudo"><span>text</span></a>
```

Comment: I thought so too, but I was asked to find another "simpler" way to achieve it without flex box. I have been banging my head for hours and I gave up in the end. Using any other workaround is so messy. Not to mention when you code in responsive design, in which the layout changes and a lot more tweak has to be done. Thanks a lot for your answer and I felt so crazy to post this question.

Comment: @TylerBean If you can wrap the text inside the anchor there is one more way. Will update my answer

Comment: @TylerBean Updated my answer

Comment: Your update version seems to be what I need. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS Tables

```css
a {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  height: 80px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 120px;
}

.without-pseudo:before {
  content: none;
}

a:hover {
  background: green;
}

a:before {
  content: ':before';
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">text</a>
<a href="#" class="without-pseudo">text</a>
```

Comment: It does the job, though if Flexbox is abusive, then this has to be even more abusive :)

Comment: I agree it's **equally** abusive but it's without using flexbox..which is what was asked

Comment: You have my +1 :)